# Shift RNN Targets for Sequence Hiccup

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a RNN to correct sentences. Decoder Inputs are Decoder Output(t-1) and I need/want to leave this as such also during training.

Often it encounters a situation in which it needs to add or delete a letter (often a space) in between some characters.

```
Example:
Inputs: I Needa sPace inbetewen
Target: I need a space inbetween
Output: I need a space inbetween
```

All is good. But if the output were:

```
Output: I needa space inbetween
```

Then my loss would explode for all signs after the missed space:

```
I - I
  -  
n - n
e - e
e - e
d - d
  - a
a -  
  - s
s - p
p - a
a - c
c - e
e -  
  - i
i - n
n - b
b - e
e - t
t - w
w - e
e - e
e - n
n - <eos>
```

So while I want a high loss at the step in which the net missed the space all further steps outputs are actually "correct" in the sense that the outputs follow the best possible sequence. Still I punish the net highly here with traditional X-entropy (labels vs. targets for each step).

Comment: This might be more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com